# Simulation of parallel port but without a parallel port

Tags: simulation, parallel, port

I've been working on a project in my faculty that requires me to use a parallel port, but as I see my laptop doesn't have one!

I've been searching for a way to simulate the parallel port on my laptop, like when I send some data to the address 378H, the program that's like the simulator will give me an indication that he has received them and so on...

I found [this website](http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=22605) but it wasn't useful. Also have been googling all the night , but didn't find any ....

If you needed any more information I will be more than happy to provide them

I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Explaining "but wasn't useful" would be a very good idea. The solution sounds potentially good - what was wrong with it?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I can't determine which lang this code was written by , so I couldn't compile it ...stupid excuse , but I always seek for a .exe solution

Comment: That code fragment would not help you, it is a stub for the parallel port access routines in some pascal-like language, not a simulated-hardware-level parallel port replacement.

Comment: I'm searching for a smiulated hardware level , I know that this is 2012 The era of USB :S

Comment: I think I've to make my own simulator .... C# here we go

Comment: 2012 may be the era of USB, but there are better IO solutions than a parallel port.  That method was neat while it lasted, but there are many new IO solutions that are faster, more robust, and offer better expansion mechanisms than parallel ports.

Comment: Actually most newer methods are far slower than parallel ports, at least when measured in terms of *latency*.  There's very little in a modern PC that can match a true local bus parallel port for low-latency performance.  Most of the tasks that were once done on the main CPU communicating over the parallel port have since had to be exported to embedded controllers with real I/O, which take higher level non-realtime "to do" lists over USB from the PC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about port-write interception on desktop operating systems rather than about electronics or embedded development.  It may also be about buying products, another topic which is prohibited here (though product purchases won't do any good without a driver that can intercept port writes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make **[this](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/basteln/PC/USB2LPT/index.en.htm)** USB2LPT adapter.

---

Added by RMc:

@xsari3x - This is capable of being a purely software solution if desired.

His english page [here](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/bastelecke/Rund%20um%20den%20PC/USB2LPT/index.html.en) notes

- "Contrary to all other USB→Parallel adapters which can connect to printers only, this makes connection to most hardware - without adapting the software! A parallel port will be virtualized by the accompanying driver. "

As he provides the driver source code [via this page](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/bastelecke/Rund%20um%20den%20PC/USB2LPT/index.html.en#driver) you will be able to bypass the hardware by modifying the source code.

Comment: I'm seeking for a pure SW solution , but this one is great :D

Comment: What do you mean by a pure software solution? How can software cause 5 V to appear on a pin on a wire that doesn't exist?

Comment: @xsari3x: If you are looking for a way to just have a software visualization of a byte located at address $378, then you should probably read it by polling with some direct port access library and visualize it's bits graphically. Asking such a question at electronics forum gives you answers you saw.

Comment: USB adapters are not true parallel ports, they are printer ports. There is a difference. Such as you cannot use FPGA parallel programming cables and such with a printer port. If you get to wanting hardware and your laptop has an ExpressCard slot, then look for a PCI-Express based (NOT USB based) parallel port card for that. I've got one that also has two serial ports, which also saved me in a class using an old Rabbit processor board and my usual USB-serial adaptor was not compatible with the Rabbit stuff.

Comment: @xsari3x - iT ISGREAT . iT IS CAPABLE OF BEING A PURELY SOFTWARE SOLUTION TOO. His english page [here](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/bastelecke/Rund%20um%20den%20PC/USB2LPT/index.html.en) notes "Contrary to all other USB→Parallel adapters which can connect to printers only, this makes connection to most hardware - without adapting the software! A parallel port will be virtualized by the accompanying driver. " and he provides the driver source code, so you will be able to bypass the hardware by modifying the source code.

Comment: This is effectively a **link-only answer**

Answer (score 1):

Summarised_Solution:

- The easiest way to do this is to add a parallel port ! :-)
- USB to parallel port converters are available - some at very modest cost. Cost starts from under $US4 including postage.

---

The easiest way to do this is to add a parallel port using an available USB to parallel port converter. These are available  on ebay for from under $US4 including postage.

This doesn't have to work very well - the main aim is probably that your code thinks it is talking to a viable port.

The two examples below are in HongKong and will mail to Egypt and total cost is allegedly under $US4. You can find many more on ebay - most in US or Asia  probably. Couldn't find any Egyptian sellers - but yiur local computer stores should have these.

[This ebay seller](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-36-Pin-Parallel-Printer-Cable-Converter-Adapter-/190435697829?pt=UK_Computing_CablesConnectors_RL&hash=item2c56da24a5#shId) in Hong Kong will provide a USB to parallel port converter for GBP1 (About $US1.50) and send it to Egypt for another GBP1. About $US3.50 all up.

[image]

[This one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-25PIN-Parallel-Port-PRINTER-Converter-CABLE-1284-/320603811586?pt=UK_Computing_CablesConnectors_RL&hash=item4aa579ef02#ht_2612wt_1021) is a similar price and same mailing charge.

[image]

Comment: I live in Egypt :D , If I ordered this it will come to me after 24 days ++ , 
Isn't there some solution In Protues or Multisim ?

Comment: @xsari3x - IIRC I think Multisim does have a parallel port component you might be able to use. Check on their site and maybe ask in the forum.

Comment: Also  note that majority of USB to parallel port cables are for printers only! This is actually quite a big problem.

Comment: Or try this one: [USB2LPT](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/bastelecke/Rund%20um%20den%20PC/USB2LPT/index.html.en)